# Django | A VIEWS no llega el argumento por GET de la url

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-views

Al tratar de filtrar por modalidad una conjunto de preguntas, la url trae por get la modadlidad de pregutas (en el siguiente ejempolo "Administrativo" sería el argumento a tomar en views.py):

**Ejemplo:**

http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/test/**Administrativo**/

Pero parece que **en la view no cojo bien ese argumento** que vendría con el nombre "questionModality" definido en urls.py

**Urls.py**

```
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views
from .views import testFilterByModalityAndByUserView

app_name = 'test_app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('test/<str:questionModality>/',
        views.testFilterByModalityAndByUserView.as_view(),
        name='test',
    ),
]
```

**Views.py**

```
class testFilterByModalityAndByUserView(ListView):
model = Test
template_name = 'test/question.html'
def get_queryset(self, questionModality):
    print(questionModality)
login_url = reverse_lazy('test_app:test')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin ver exactamente el error que te muestra Django es difícil dar una respuesta correcta, pero de momento veo un fallo en cómo haces la consulta en la vista.

Las vistas de clase genéricas tienen un modo predefinido de obtener los resultados de las consultas a base de datos, y en concreto una `ListView` lo que hace es el equivalente a la consulta `Modelo.objects.all()`. Puedes variarlo con el parámetro, por supuesto, pero entonces la función tiene que realizar esta otra consulta:

```
def get_queryset(self, questionModality):
    return Test.objects.filter(question_modality=questionModality)
```

De hecho puedes ahorrarte la función y declarar directamente el parámetro:

```
class testFilterByModalityAndByUserView(ListView):
    model = Test
    template_name = 'test/question.html'
    queryset = Test.objects.filter(question_modality=questionModality)
```

Los objetos de tipo ListView no tienen un comportamiento definido para redirecciones o login, tal y como lo tienes definido `login_url` no tiene ningún sentido en la clase.